# Remember, recall, memorize a forgotten word

Tags: differences

Situtation: I have a conversation and want to say "The door is closed" but I forget the word "closed". So I ask my conversational partner to help me. Which words are the best, which can be acceptable and which are wrong:

> A: "Look. The door is .... Mmmm... I don't remember that word. Can you remind me it?"
>
> B: Can't you **remember it/recall it/call it to your mind**? You have to **remember/memorize**: the door is "closed"!

Comment: Corollary to the definition of a synonym:  A synonym is a word you use instead of the word you can't think of.  (The base definition is that a synonym is a word you use in place of a word you don't remember how to spell.)  In other words, "The door is shut."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appropriate responses could be:

> A: "Look. The door is .... Mmmm... I don't remember the **right** word. Can you **remind me of it/refresh my memory**?"
>
> B: Can't you **remember it/recollect it**? You have to **remember/retain this in memory**: the door is "closed"!

*Call it to mind* is more formal and may not be commonly used in casual conversation.

*remind me/refresh my memory* are nearly synonymous.

**EDIT:**

This [link](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/memory/memory.html) describing common English phrases regarding *memory* and *remembering* may help.

Comment: I read that I can't "recall" forgotten things.  I understand that was wrong. Can you describe deference between "recall a forgotten word" and "remember a forgotten word"?

Comment: It's *recollect*, not *recall*. You can attempt to recollect something which has been forgotten. Forgotten doesn't mean erased from mind. It could still be there somewhere in the back of your mind.

Comment: See the link I just added.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and link. So am I right: remember = keep in mind, recall = get from mind?

Comment: *remember= keep in mind*, yes, but "get from mind" is not grammatically correct. "bring to mind" or "call to mind" can be used in formal writing.

Comment: Aha. Recall = bring to mind. I want to say: remember is something fixed, recall - action. Right?